# why when going back to the previous page, it is always the top of the page?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to implement a back button to my page to go back to the previous page, here is my attempt:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back);
```

and in the `Manifest` I set the parent to this activity:

```
 <activity android:name=".ui.Rem.Stories.s19" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
```

but the issue is when I go back to the previous page it is always the top of the page, I want the previous page to be as it was left off when, why does it go back to the top always? How can I fix this? please help.